# Insert Multi Row Oracle result set into MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

A little background. I have an Oracle database that I am trying to query and then insert into a local MYSQL database so that I can generate canned reports. I have been trying to figure out this insert into Mysql for a while now. I have the Oracle portion running correctly but when I try to insert I have been getting a syntax error in mysql.

The result set comes back with 8 rows the first of which is the Key in MYSQL. I would really like to convert this insert query I built into a insert on duplicate key update statement but am lost on how I would do this properly. Any help you guys can provide would be appreciated.

```
$db1 = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HOST)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=Service)))';

$c1 = oci_connect("Userid", "Pass", $db1);   

$sql = oci_parse($c1, "select statement") ;

oci_execute($sql);

$i = 0;

   while ($row = oci_fetch_array($sql)){
   $i++;
    $k = $row[0];
    $dte = $row[1];
    $cus = $row[2];
    $odr = $row[3];
    $lin = $row[4];
    $cas = $row[5];
    $lpo = $row[6];
    $cpl = $row[7];
    $cpo = $row[8];
   };

$db_user = "userid";

$db_pass = "Pass";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=host; dbname=databasename', $db_user, $db_pass);

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `cuspi` (k, dte, cus, odr, lin, casa, lpo, cpl, cpo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$recordcount = count($k);
 for ($i = 0; $i < $recordcount; $i++) {
  $records[] = [
  $k[$i],
  $dte[$i],
  $cus[$i],
  $odr[$i],
  $lin[$i],
  $casa[$i],
  $lpo[$i],
  $cpl[$i],
  $cpo[$i],
 ];
 }


foreach ($records as $record) {
$stmt->execute($record);
}
?>
```

Comment: So, what is the syntax error?

Comment: Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lin, casa, lpo, cpl, cpo) VALUES ('0', '0', 'N', '1', '6', '6', '6', '1', '6'' at line 1 ) array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "N" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(1) "6" [5]=> string(1) "6" [6]=> string(1) "6" [7]=> string(1) "1" [8]=> string(1) "6" } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the Answer. I was missing the grave accent around the column references for the insert.

Original

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `cuspi` (k, dte, cus, odr, lin, casa, lpo, cpl, cpo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Fixed

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `cuspi` (`k`, `dte`, `cus`, `odr`, `lin`, `casa`, `lpo`, `cpl`, `cpo`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```